# React hook not updating after the API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using the MUI progress bar in order to show the process and manually setting the value of the progress by a variable. The functional component renders well and I can update the value of the progress bar but it seems it does not work after the api call.
Also I am updating the value of the progress bar while my search takes place and the results are being sent as params to another component onSearchComplete.

```
function LinearProgressWithLabel(props: LinearProgressProps & { value: number }) {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Box sx={{ width: '100%', mr: 1 }}>
          <LinearProgress variant="determinate" {...props} />
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 65 }}>
          <Text><Typography variant="body2">{`${Math.round(
            props.value,
          )}%`}</Typography></Text>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    );
  }

export const Search = (props) => {

    const { contacts, setContacts, onSearchComplete } = props;

    const [msgBox, setMsgBox] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(10);
    let progressValue = 0;
    const onSearch = async () => {

        setLoading(true);
       
            progressValue = 30;
        try {
            //setting progressValue = 60 here works fine. 
   
            const searchResults = await AppApi.searchMany(emails); //making the api call

            progressValue = 80; //this value does not work

            let userList = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
               
             //processing the result here. 

                }
                userList = [...userList, ..._users];
            }
            progressValue = 95;
            userList.sort(sortByEmail);

            onSearchComplete(userList);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log({ err });
            setMsgBox({ message: `${err.message}`, type: 'error' });
        }

        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        onSearch();
      }, []);
      useEffect(() => {
            setProgress(() => progressValue);
        }, [progressValue]);


    return (
        <Box>
           
            {loading ?   <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />:
            <Box>{msgBox && (<a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => setMsgBox(null)} title="Click  to dismiss"><MessageBox type={msgBox.type || 'info'}>{msgBox.message}</MessageBox></a>)}</Box>}


        </Box>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`progressValue` will be redeclared `0` each render cycle. Just enqueue state updates to the `progress` state.

```
export const Search = (props) => {
  const { contacts, setContacts, onSearchComplete } = props;

  const [msgBox, setMsgBox] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(10);

  const onSearch = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setProgress(30);

    try {
      const searchResults = await AppApi.searchMany(emails);
      setProgress(80);

      let userList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
        //processing the result here. 
        userList = [...userList, ..._users];
      }
      setProgress(95);
      userList.sort(sortByEmail);

      onSearchComplete(userList);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ err });
      setMsgBox({ message: `${err.message}`, type: 'error' });
    }

    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onSearch();
  }, []);

  return (...);
}
```

[image: Edit react-hook-not-updating-after-the-api-call]

Comment: Hi @drew this doesnt work. I tried enqueueing the state updates but it just stays static.

Comment: @JainamShah It should work. `onSearch` is `async` so any enqueued state updates will process while waiting for the asynchronous code to resolve. Where are you seeing it "stay static"? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you are having that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: what I mean is,  <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />: doesnt show the updated value. It remains the same even if the value for progress changes. So the % shows - 30% only.

Comment: @JainamShah Seems to work fine. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-not-updating-after-the-api-call-cpuz8n) demo. I've artificially inserted some "sleep" functions so you can see the state/progress update "incrementally". I think the issue you are seeing is that after the `AppApi.searchMany(emails);` all the code is *completely* synchronous, so the progress is immediately completed. Does that make sense?